# Twisted supermultiplets

Tags: quantum-field-theory, supersymmetry, gauge-theory, particle-physics

What is a twisted supermultiplet, in a generic supersymmetric theory?
Which ordinary fields belong to one of such twisted supermultiplets?

I am confident with the idea of a supermultiplet or a superfield, in $\mathcal{N}=1,2,4$.
However, I don't know what the term *twisted* stands for.

Also, why is it useful to consider such things?

Comment: The only twisted multiplet that springs to my mind is in $d=2,\ \mathcal{N}=2$ where there are two kinds of chiral multiplets called chiral and twisted chiral multiplets. Here they are related by mirror symmetry.

Comment: See A Chockalingham and C J Isham 1980 J. Phys. A: Math. Gen. 13 2723 doi:10.1088/0305-4470/13/8/021